# A C++ error that I don't understand

Tags: c++

So this is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int kol=0, x;

cout << "Insert a number: ";
cin >> x;

while (x > 0);
{
    div_t output;
    output = x;
    x = div(output, 10);
    kol += kol;
}
cout << "Amount: " << kol << endl;
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

And I got this error:
Error   1   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversation)

Can someone tell me what I did wrong, and how to fix?

Comment: x is type `int`, youre assigning to output which is type `div_t`, does `div_t` have an `operator=` taking an `int` (or something else that has an implicit conversion from `int`)?

Comment: Programming by guessing doesn't work. What was `output = x` intended to accomplish, and where did you read that it should be done that way? We need to correct that resource. Also please make your title describe the question; "an error that I don't understand" in a list of questions helps nobody.

Answer (score 3):

You are treating div_t like an int; it isn't one.  It's a struct.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div

Can you expound on what you are trying to do? Clearly, there's repetitive division intended, but that's all I surmise.

Comment: A bit more coding sample how to fix the OP's source would make your answer really great,

Answer (score 0):

`output` is a `div_t`. `x` is an `int`, so `output = x` is like trying to assign an apple to an orange. You can't do it without establishing a set of rules for turning the apple into an orange.

We could try to write such a rule, but why bother? Instead let's look at the code that got us into this predicament and try to figure out the context.

```
while (x > 0);
{
    div_t output;
    output = x;
    x = div(output, 10);
    kol += kol;
}
```

The purpose of this loop seems to be to count of the number of times `x` was divided by ten and store the count in `kol`.

`div_t` is the result of a call to `div`, so assigning a value to the result before performing the operation that will generate the result is a touch unusual. Perhaps OP meant

```
while (x > 0);
{
    div_t output;
    output = div(x, 10);
    kol += kol;
}
```

to divide `x` by ten and get the quotient and remainder.

But this loop will never exit because `x` is never changed. If it is not zero, the loop will never terminate and if it is zero the loop will never enter. Perhaps

```
while (x > 0);
{
    div_t output;
    output = div(x, 10);
    x = output.quot;
    kol += kol;
}
```

would be more appropriate. The remainder is never used however, so `div` is effectively wasted and

```
while (x > 0);
{
    x = x / 10; // or x /= 10;
    kol += kol;
}
```

would provide the same result with far less fuss.